# Generic problem with networkmanager on Ubuntu 12.04 / elementaryOS

Tags: 12.04, unity, network-manager, gnome-panel, elementary

Hello together: Since some days I've got issues with the networkmanager under Ubuntu 12.04. To be concrete it is the nm-applet itself. I can connect via LAN or WLAN without problems, but some entries within the applet are disabled and not usable. So I can't disconnect or create new VPN-connection using the submenu for exmaple. Also I can't edit my network-connection. The call of `nm-connection-editor` using the terminal is possible so far. But it is irritating and not very helpful having the applet in this state. Has somebody experience what is causing this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But this is a question about a package installable from the officual repositories of UBUNTU. The network-manager and network-manager-gnome are part of the distribution and this is not about Ubuntu? Please help me to understand: Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution: From my point of view it seems to be an error within the last upate of the package `network-manager-gnome`, which was released 2015-02-16 (http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/updates/network-manager-gnome). I've tried to find the concrete error and so I've tried to use an older package version: The problem was no more present and the applet is useful as always. The problem within: The unity-greeter was also updated and breaks the package. The final solution for now is little easier:

1. Just download the deb-package for your platform (amd64 or i386) (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/network-manager-gnome).
2. Unpack the concurrent deb-package and copy the included version of nm-applet under `/usr/bin/nm-applet` - make a copy / backup of your present version.
3. Restart your system and everything should work as always.